# 1099'd Telecommuter - I work by phone from SC with CA company - who gets state tax?

Tags: united-states, california, form-1099, state-taxes, south-carolina

I am a 1099'd telecommuter that used to live in California.
I moved to South Carolina in 2017.
I need to file 2017 taxes with 4 months in CA, 8 months in SC.
In 2018 I will need to file 12 months in SC.

Who do I pay state tax to for each of these years?

Thanks so much for your advice.  I appreciate it very much!!!

Comment: when you moved to SC was it a permanent move? I am not sure where the difficulty is. Doesn't SC want to tax the income your earned over the last 8 months?

Comment: Yes, SC is a permanent move.  I got 1099's from CA - do I have to pay CA only for the months I worked there, and pay SC for the months I worked in LA by phone, from SC?  Or do I pay all to SC?

Comment: it's simply where you live.

Comment: Since I lived in CA for 4 months, do I only pay CA for the income earned when I lived there?  Then pay SC for only the income earned in the 8 months I telecommuted to CA from SC?   Thanks for your advice!